# SQL Server: WHERE Clause to exclude data in selection

Tags: sql-server, where-clause

I have a table with persons, an `inactive-flag` (bit) indicating active/nonactive and `fromdate`, `todate`.

- a) Inactive=1 indicates that someone is general "not active".
  If there is a date in fromdate and todate field that means that in general he is not active `EXCEPT` during this date-period.
- b) Inactive=0 indicates that someone is general "active".
  If there is a date in `fromdate` and `todate` field that means that in general he is active `EXCEPT` during this date-period.
- c) Last Option are persons who have only Inactive=0, without any date exception (fromdate and todate field are `NULL`).

I want to filter all persons a) and c), except b).

I tried a lot, but could not solve the Problem.

I found the solution for a) and c) but not for b).
I tried for b):

```
WHERE inaktiv=0 AND (Not (fromdate >=convert(date,getdate()) AND todate <=convert(date,getdate())))
```

Comment: you can use "union" with multi select statment

Comment: why do you want b) cases if you want only a) and c) cases ?

Comment: You forgot `or Inactive=1`. Also confusing negation of comparison to date could be absolutely clear `(fromdate<@date and todate > @date)`

Answer (score 0):

To get a) and c) cases :

```
WHERE inaktiv=1 OR (inaktiv=0 AND fromdate IS NULL AND todate IS NULL)
```

Comment: Both, fromdate and todate have Dates, so todate cannot be NULL. I have to check both Dates. My Problem is b). a) and c) are solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think I did it after many Trials:

```
WHERE ((inaktiv=0  and (not (convert(date,getdate()) between aktivVon AND  aktivBis))))
or ((inaktiv=0) and (aktivVon is null AND  aktivBis is null))
or ((inaktiv=1 and  (convert(date,getdate()) between aktivVon AND  aktivBis)))
```

The last line is b).
Please confirm my solution, I hope I did not Forget anything.
Michael